# Does the Master Theorem apply to T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/log2(n)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, master-theorem

Id say this is the first case of Master Theorem, but when I try to prove that the limit of f(n)/ n ^ (1-E) is 0, I cannot do it. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is [Case 2b from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form): here $a = b = 3$ and $f(n) = n/\log n = n^{\log_b a} \cdot \log^{k}(n)$ for $k = -1$. Thus, the solution is $\Theta(n\log \log n)$.